Shopify Product image slider/carousel
I'm currently building a Shopify website using the Impulse theme, and I'm looking to incorporate a slider for product images that automatically switches after a couple of seconds. However, I haven't had success in implementing this feature so far. Despite watching several YouTube tutorials and consulting various online resources, I haven't found a solution.
I attempted to modify the theme files, including "theme.liquid" and "product-image.liquid", by adding code, but it hasn't yielded the desired outcome.
